# android startmanagingcursor from ArrayAdapter Class

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-arrayadapter

I need to access a database from within an arrayAdapter class I am using to populate a custom ListView. However, the startmanagingcursor is undefined for ArrayAdapters.

Here is a code snippet:

```
DB myDb= new DB(this);
myDb.open();
Cursor c = myDb.getInfo(sillyString);
startManagingCursor(c);
```

Comment: Please don't use `startManagingCursor`... it is deprecated and is very bad practice! Read here: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `startManagingCursor()`-method is deprecated anyways. If you're targeting Devices with Android 3.0 you can use a [CurserLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html).

If not, you may want to create the cursor for a global object and close it in your `onStop`-method.

Comment: I am not supporting 3.0 devices at this point. my minimum sdk is 1.6. Don't ask me, its what the customer wants.

Comment: Then, you shouldn't use the `startManagingCursor`-method and close it yourself (if you need to).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need ArrayAdapter for this?
It seems [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) is more appropriate here.

Comment: the arrayadapter is populating a view used in a custom ListView. The data comes in from a webservice as JSON, I parse the data into an object. this arrayadapter class takes the object and populates the view. The reason for the DB look up is to do a look up on value of one of the object properties. 
For example, the webservice returns a code value in the JSON of 'abc' this value ends up in the object class. When I populate the view, I need to use the DB to find a more user-friendly name for the code. Does that make sense?